# How to add a new field to dataset without CreateDataset?

Tags: delphi, runtime, field, tclientdataset

I have a dataset TclientDataSet where the fields are created by code.
I need the user to append these with additional fields while preserving existing data.

```
`MYclientDataSet.FieldDefs.Add(s, ftString, 20);
 MYclientDataSet.CreateDataset;
 MYclientDataSet.Open;
 MYclientDataSet.edit;
 MYclientDataSet.FieldByName(s).AsString := 'Test';
 MYclientDataSet.post;`
```

This works but CreateDataset erases all the data. 
Is there any way of adding the new field to the dataset?

I have tried many other solutions but none seem to work

many thanks

Comment: Could you add some detail about the other solutions you've tried already?

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the following code, which basically saves the current data, creates the new field structure and copies the saved data back:

```
var
  cds: TClientDataSet;
begin
  cds := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    cds.Data := MyClientDataSet.Data;
    MyClientDataSet.Close;
    MyClientDataSet.FieldDefs := cds.FieldDefs;
    MyClientDataSet.FieldDefs.Add('Note', ftString, 20);
    MyClientDataSet.CreateDataSet;
    cds.First;
    while not cds.Eof do begin
      MyClientDataSet.Append;
      MyClientDataSet.CopyFields(cds);
      MyClientDataSet.FieldByName('Note').AsString := 'Test';
      MyClientDataSet.Post;
      cds.Next;
    end;
  finally
    cds.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This works fine.  On inspecting the contents of the XML file, `MyClientDataSet.Post;` was inserting an extra row of data since I used savetofile before closing the application.  So post was removed

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about fields of type `fkData`, i.e. ones which would be included in the CDS's saved data, you cannot add such fields once the CDS is already open.

The simplest way I know of to achieve the equivalent effect is to

1. Save the CDS data to XML.
2. Modify the metadata in the XML which defines the fkData fields, to add the ones you want.
3. Save the XML.
4. Reload the CDS from the XML.

I think I posted an example of how to do this in a reply to an SO q a while ago.  If I can find it, I'll add a link to it later on.